# Can't deploy resources due to virtual network outside resource group in Azure

Tags: azure

I am pretty new to ARM templates and am still learning Azure. I am trying to deploy an Azure project from github (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-av-automation). This project basically contains functions to sort files based on if they are malicious or clean within an existing storage account.

I am trying to use the existing vnet variation custom ARM template they provide (I will provide a link below). This template only allows to deploy to an existing virtual network inside of the same resource group. I want to deploy to an existing virtual network contained within another resource group. When deploying, I get this error: *The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet_01' under resource group 'test_deploy_1_rg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix (Code: ResourceNotFound)* I did already follow the instructions such as changing the existing storage account's network settings to include the virtual network I desire and adding the appropriate subnets. **How would I modify the ARM template they provide to deploy the resources to an existing vnet contained within another resource group?** Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

*Link to ARM template: [Given ARM Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-av-automation/blob/main/ARM_template/AVAutomationForStorageExistingVnetTemplate.json)*

[image: Instructions prior to deploying ARM template]

Answer (score 0):

To deploy an Azure project to an existing virtual network in another resource group, you need to specify the resource group name and the virtual network ID in the ARM template parameters. You also need to make sure that the virtual network has a subnet that matches the subnet name in the template, for instance this is an example of how to modify the ARM template parameters to use an existing virtual network in another resource group:

```json
"parameters": {
  ...
  "virtualNetworkName": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Existing VNet Name"
    }
  },
  "virtualNetworkResourceGroup": {
    "type": "string",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Resource group of the existing VNet"
    }
  },
  ...
},
"variables": {
  ...
  "vnetId": {
    "existing": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I added the updated parameters along with the vnetId variable. I added the vnetId variable to the resourceId functions within the template: "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnetId'), variables('functionSubnetName'))]" I am now getting a validation error stating "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'vnet_analytics_001/VMSubnet' at line '281' and column '9' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': all function arguments must be string literals. What do I need to change within the resourceId functions?